# Handling entities inheritance spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm working with this [tutorial](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/12/18/handling-entities-inheritance-with-spring-data-jpa/) to handle entities inheritance. I have person and company entities that extends the User entity.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public abstract class User { 

@Id
private long id;

@NotNull
private String email;

// getters and settres
}

@Entity
public class Person extends User { 
private int age;
// getters and settres and other attributs
}

@Entity
public class Company extends User { 
private String companyName;
// getters and settres and other attribut
}
```

then UserRpository ,PersonRepository and Company Repository that extends the UserBaseRepository.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface UserBaseRepository<T extends User> 
extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {

public T findByEmail(String email);

}

@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends UserBaseRepository<User> { }

@Transactional
public interface PersonRepository extends UserBaseRepository<Person> { }

@Transactional
public interface CompanyRepository extends UserBaseRepository<Company> { }
```

the probleme is when calling personRepository.findAll() to get all persons , in result i got also companies.

Comment: I cloned the project from the tutorial and everything works as expected. How does the SQL look like that Hibernate is generating? And what Spring Version are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your issue is with the "Discriminator" column that JPA requires. You are using the `@Inheritance` annotation and by default that will use the `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` strategy. That means the following:

1. Your inherited entities `Person` and `Company` will go into a single table.
2. JPA will require a Discriminator to differentiate between entity types.

I did the following to make it work for your use case:

***Entities:***

```
@Inheritance
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_table")
public abstract class User {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String email;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Company  extends User {

    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Person extends User {

    @Column
    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

***DB Schema:***

```
-- user table
create table user_table (
  id BIGINT         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email             VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    age               INT,
    company_name      VARCHAR(50),
    dtype             VARCHAR(80) -- Discriminator
);
```

***Some test data:***

```
insert into user_table(id, dtype, age, email) values
(1,'Person', 25, 'john.doe@email.com'),
(2,'Person',22, 'jane.doe@email.com');

insert into user_table(id, dtype, company_name, email) values
(3,'Company','Acme Consultants', 'acme@company.com'),
(4,'Company', 'Foo Consultants', 'foo@company.com');
```

***Repositories:***

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface UserBaseRepository<T extends User> extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {

    T findByEmail(String email);
}

@Transactional
public interface PersonRepository extends UserBaseRepository<Person> {

}

@Transactional
public interface CompanyRepository extends UserBaseRepository<Company> {

}
```

***JUnit Tests:***

```
public class MultiRepositoryTest extends BaseWebAppContextTest {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGetPersons() {
        List<Person> target = new ArrayList<>();
        personRepository.findAll().forEach(target::add);
        Assert.assertEquals(2, target.size());
    }
    @Test
    public void testGetCompanies() {
        List<Company> target = new ArrayList<>();
        companyRepository.findAll().forEach(target::add);
        Assert.assertEquals(2, target.size());
    }

}
```

The above tests pass. That indicates JPA now utilizes the discriminator correctly to retrieve the required records.

For JPA related theory for your question, see this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html).

Comment: @Achraf if this worked for you, can you please go ahead and accept this as an answer?